# How can I escape '%' character in a gettext string?

Tags: gettext, string-formatting

I use [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) to translate my user interface. I'd like to write symbol `%` as part of a UI caption in a string, but since it has a special meaning, does not works as expected. How can I escape percent symbols?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `%%` to escape %.

Comment: If I'm right, the same rules apply here as in `sprintf`-like string formatting.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case with python though
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730770/translating-with-gettext-and-jinja2-and-pyramid