# Why gettext (Python) does not work without .mo files?

Tags: python, gettext

Gettext in my application gives the following error when .mo files are removed from .../LC_MESSAGES but .po files are there:

```
No translation file found for domain', domain)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'bot'
```

What can be the reason? I saw some projects without .mo files and they worked. For example, .mo files are stated in Python gitignore file (https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore; line 55) so they should be removed the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.po` files are the source files, but the `.mo` files are the compiled translation catalogs used at runtime. The short answer therefore is that gettext only searches for `.mo` files and not `.po` files, and that is by design.

It is true that some frameworks use `.po` files directly at runtime but Python gettetxt obviously does not and there are good reasons for that design decision. Please see [Benefits of compiling po files to mo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743208/benefits-of-compiling-po-files-to-mo/53819204#53819204) where I have already elaborated on that topic.